# Accessing parent POM properties from Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Spring application that is built using Maven. Jenkins Declarative pipeline is being used for achieving CI/CD.

I want my Jenkinsfile to be as generic as possible, leveraging what's already available from the POM along with its parent POM. We use a custom Super POM to centralize metadata such as our Artifactory repositories (distributionManagement />), SonarQube servers and some other valuable properties.

I'm already using `readMavenPom().getParent().getGroupId()` to fetch our company's standard groupId, along with `readMavenPom().getArtifactId()`, `readMavenPom().getVersion()` and `readMavenPom().getPackaging()`.

I'd like to access the  metadata so I can use it for the pipeline step that publishes binaries to Artifactory.

Looking at the [Parent class](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Parent.html), I don't see any getter for the distributionManagement tag. I do see it under [ModelBase](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/ModelBase.html) though.

How can I access those details from the Jenkinsfile?

Thank you

Comment: I would check for `readMavenPom().getDistributionManagement()` see http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html (inherited things from ModelBase)... I see it under ModelBase http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/ModelBase.html#getDistributionManagement()

Comment: I had already tried it. Since my POM doesn't include a distributionManagement tag (since the data is inherited from the parent POM), it returns null.

Comment: Ah..Ok. So the inheritance is not available in Jenkins that will become a little bit harder..First what are you trying to do ? Can you elaborate that a little bit more ? What are you fetching the company groupId ?

Comment: In fact, I need to fetch the distributionManagement tag for getting the Artifactory repositories (release and snapshot). They were added to the Super POM as an effort to reuse code as much as possible and avoid repeating this tag over and over again in the different projects. The same applies with the groupId. It's always the same, so it's now in our parent POM for simplicity and reuse purposes.

Comment: The point is the inheritance solution is only done in Maven itself but not in Jenkins...you might try to get this via `mvn -N help:effective-pom -Doutput=result.xml`...and give a parameter to `readMavenPom('result.xml')`?

Comment: @khmarbaise please post your answer as a solution. That works wonders. I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is the inheritance solution is only done in Maven itself but not in Jenkins.
You might try to get this via `mvn -N help:effective-pom -Doutput=result.xml` and give a parameter to `readMavenPom('result.xml')`